# SQL where particular column values appears

Tags: mysql, sql

I wasn't sure how to really search for this..

Lets say I have a simple table like this

```
ID     Type
1      0
1      1
2      1
3      0
4      0
4      1
```

How could I select all ID's which have a type of both 0 and 1?

Comment: `SELECT ID FROM table WHERE Type IN ( 0, 1 )`

Comment: @Danijel That will select everything in that example table. The OP just wants 1 and 4.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT id,type
FROM t
GROUP BY id 
HAVING SUM(type=0)>0
AND SUM(type=1)>0
```

You just group by id ,than with HAVING you use post aggregation filtering to check for 0 and 1.

Comment: To explain, this groups the data into sets per ID, then counts the number of rows in each set matching the expression `type=0` and `type=1` - as long as both of these expression are true for a given group, it returns that group in the result set.

Answer (score 2):

Having is pretty expensive and that query can't hit keys.

```
SELECT ID FROM foo AS foo0 JOIN foo AS foo1 USING (ID) WHERE foo0.Type=0 AND foo1.Type=1 GROUP BY foo0.id.
```

Answer (score 1):

A more generalized way of doing this would by to use a CASE column for each value you need to test combined with a GROUP BY on the id column.  This means that if you have n conditions to test for, you would have a column indicating if each condition is met for a given id.  Then the HAVING condition becomes trivial and you can use it like any multi-column filter, or use the grouping as your subquery and the code looks simpler and the logic becomes even easier to follow.

```
SELECT id, Type0,Type1 
FROM (
     SELECT id, 
       Type0 = max(CASE WHEN type = 0 THEN TRUE END)
       , Type1 = max(CASE WHEN type = 1 THEN TRUE END)
     FROM t
     GROUP BY id
     ) pivot
WHERE Type0 = TRUE and Type1 = TRUE
```

Comment: Will not use indexes.